# Rapid Application Development Or Good Programming Practice? Which one do you choose

Tags: orm

Are ORM frameworks such as Entity Framework, Linq to SQL, Subsonic, NHibernate promote good programming practice or just a tools to speed up the development?

Should we used this technologies inside the presentation layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can do both.  With any techlonogy there are good practices and there are bad.

ORM Frameworks can or cannot speed up development, a good design has more impact on development time than the tools used.  The advantages are getting all you business logic in one place and removing it from the data portion.

I would not use them in a presentation layer, but have you presentation or UI layer call a business layer which would call a data layer.

Comment: But ORMs are also data layer right?
Presentation Layer should have no dependency on Data Access Layer.

Comment: ORM are a data layer.  But the data layer should only be called by the business layer.  The UI should only call the business layer.  The business layer has all the business rules for the system.

Comment: This may sound obvious to a lot of readers, but there's a good point made here -- I've seen too many apps that rely too heavily on the existence of a particular ORM from within the presentation layer. Separation of concerns, people.

Answer (score 2):

Rapid Application Development always.

As a freelance contract programmer my ability to satisfy clients is directly related to my productivity.  On any new job I generally have a few days, at most, to show some kind of results.  So I'm entirely oriented towards finding and using the best tools to help me produce good programs in the shortest amount of time.

Within that constraint, I hope I pay attention to good programming practices.  By the best practices in the world are no good to me, or to my client, if the project is abandoned or given to someone else while I'm still modelling or refactoring.

Comment: With respect, feh.  I maintain both my own code, sometimes from 10 or 15 years ago, code I inherit from other outside or inside developers, and the code I share with inside developers at my clients.  In addition, I have a string of "thanks for the maintainable code" compliments from IT directors who've had to make modifications themselves when a programmer wasn't available.

Comment: "thanks for the maintainable code". That IT director doesnt know how to program thats why He passed it to you. This is the evidence >> "By the best practices in the world are no good to me, or to my client".

Answer (score 0):

Usually both. Sometimes you might want to write your sql by hand, but most of the time defining a model using any ORM framework will allow your object flow in your application to flow better.

Answer (score 0):

Which 1 is correct?

Design 1

+Presentation : *BLL
+BLL : *DAL 
+DAL : *ORM Framework

Design 2

+Presentation : *BLL
+BLL : *DAL, *Framework

Design 3
+Presentation : *BLL, *ORM
+BLL : *DAL, *ORM 
+DAL : *ORM Framework

**+projectname

*reference**

if none is correct please post your design..